# How to save textual content in python using minimum disk space? Is a technique like converting to binary a viable option?

Tags: python, optimization, text

I would like to save some data in text files using python and parse it later. What technique would enable me to do this the quickest(without using a database engine)? Should I convert the string to binary and save the content?

Comment: How large will these files be, what storage or transmission media are they being stored or transmitted on, and are you sure the compression is necessary?

Comment: Each file may be holding a minimum of 250mb of data. Referring to storage media, its a 7200 RPM hard disk. I was wondering if I had to scale up say I have 2000 times the current data in the next 3 years, what would be a good strategy? I am parsing the files to search for content.

Comment: If you plan on regularly searching 500GB, you should consider an actual database.

Comment: Yes I do understand that it is perhaps the more reliable solution. However, I was curious to know if there was an optimized way of solving this with the text-file approach.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend `gzip` or `Huffman coding` - both being very good for textual data compression.
- https://docs.python.org/2/library/gzip.html
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding

Using `gzip` in python is straight forward:

```
import gzip
content = "Lots of content here"

with gzip.open('file.txt.gz', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(content)

with gzip.open('file.txt.gz', 'rb') as f:
    file_content = f.read()
```